# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor how to define rule with regex

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a link like `http://www.example.com/kaufen/105975478`

I only want to allow links that have "/kaufen/" in the url and which contain a 9 digit integer number at the end of the url.

I managed to allow only links containing "/kaufen/" with the following allow statement:

```
allow=('/kaufen/', )
```

How can I extend the allow statement such that it only follows the links having a 9 digit number at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\/kaufen\/[0-9]{9}`

- `\/kaufen\/` means /kaufen/ litteraly
- `[0-9]{9}` means 9 number chars

https://regex101.com/r/tH5pC7/1

```js
var re = /\/kaufen\/[0-9]{9}/gi; 
var str = 'http://www.homegate.ch/kaufen/105975478';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Comment: Did you see the `Python` tag?

Comment: @Jan Yes, but code snippets are only available in js. I gave the regex answer. If you read the question, you see OP has no problem with the code around the regex.

Comment: But there are a couple of differences between the languages, for example you don't need to escape the slashes: https://regex101.com/r/tH5pC7/2, additionally `[0-9]` can be shortened to `\d+`. Regarding the slashes, this is what `r...` is for in `Python`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
allow=(r'kaufen/\d+$')
```